# Flexbox css works on IE/Chrome/Firefox but not on Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

On a website I'm developing I use the following css to have sticky footer as explained in (philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)

```
.Site {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;

}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

This works fine on all browsers (IE, Chrome and Firefox) but not on Microsoft Edge.
On Microsoft Edge the page is displayed incorrectly.

This happens as soon as I put the flex-direction in the css. 
However flex-direction seems to be supported by Edge (www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property).

Any idea what might be the possible cause for this?

EDIT:

Here is some more information.

- I use the Rinjani Template (themes.lucky-roo.com/rinjani-v2.1/1-rinjani-single-image/index.html).
- I basically just did what is described on the flexbox demo: I added the above css to the main css file and I added `class="Site"` to the body tag.

This is what I get on:
[Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHDvR.png)

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q46j1.png) is what it is supposed to look, and how it looks on: Chrome, FireFox and IE.

Comment: You should post enough code to reproduce the problem. And when you say the page displays "incorrectly", what does that mean? Maybe post some images showing current rendering and what you want.

Comment: Have you tried the sticky-footer demo that you linked to with Edge, and did that work? Also, you have `display: inline-flex` while the demo uses `display: flex` - have you tried that?

Comment: @Michael_B I posted a link to the template I use in the EDIT, but I don't think I just can share the code because of the license from the template. You can see the incorrect display in the images.

@StephenP Yes I tried the demo with a clean template on Edge, but it failed as you can see in the images in EDIT. I also tried a lot of different combinations, also one with `display: flex`. But none of them seem to work.

Comment: I can confirm the sticky footer flex solution works on Firefox, Chrome, Brave but NOT Edge! Four years later, it just doesn't work - still.